# Werid behavior of django model save method. "(1048, "Column 'created_at' cannot be null")" on field that has auto_now_add=True

Tags: django, database

When I am trying to save (edit) my model based form, django shows (1048, "Column 'created_at' cannot be null"), but created_at has `auto_now_add=True`.

**Here's the code:**

View:

```
def post(self, request, track_id):
        track_form = forms.AddTrack(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if track_form.is_valid():
            record = track_form.save(commit=False)
            record.id = track_id
            record.author = request.user
            record.save()

            # Let's let template know that new track was created!
            #request.session['track_created'] = True

            return HttpResponseRedirect("/mytrack/15")
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/nothing/nothing/nothing/")
```

Model:

```
class Track(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    miniature = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/track', default="defaults/default.png", validators=[validate_miniature_file_extension])
    audio_or_video = models.FileField(upload_to='audio_and_video/', default="file_not_found", validators=[validate_track_file_extension])
    favourite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

URL:

```
path('track/<int:track_id>', track.as_view(), name='track'),
```

Form:

```
class AddTrack(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Track
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'audio_or_video', 'miniature', 'favourite']
        widgets = {
            'description': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 10}),
        }
```

Comment: Does your form contain any reference to `created_at`? Your form should not show this field.

Comment: My form doesn't contain any reference to this field. I updated my answer also (I provided forms.AddTrack form).

Comment: I put an example in the answer. Let's see if the error stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about "edit", so try retrieving your model first and pass it to the form.

```
model = Track.objects.get(pk=track_id)
form = forms.AddTrack(request.POST, instance=model)
form.save()
```

Comment: Works perfectly!